# Выравнивание текста по вертикальному центру

Tags: html, css

Нужно вывести текст внутри круга, но как его выровнять по вертикальному центру?

```html
<div style="margin: 0px auto; border-radius: 100%; color: #09ab8d; border: 2px solid #09ab8d; width: 60px; height: 60px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 25px; text-align: center;">1</div>
```

Comment: добавить display: grid; place-items: center center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведенном в вопросе случае можно добавить `line-height:60px`

```css
.circle {
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid ;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">1</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Используя `display: flex` - текст внутри будет всегда в центре и по середине в зависимости от размера **parent** блока

```css
.circle {
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #09ab8d;
    border: 2px solid #09ab8d;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">1</div>
```